# Capturing values from outside a Form with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, forms, variables

Full page is at http://f14.co/auto-search/reno

I have the following checkbox set up outside a form:

```
<div class='span5' style='margin-left:0px !important;'>
    <label for='model0'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="model0x" id="model0x"
    value="Accord" style='margin-top:-5px !important;'> Accord</label>
</div>
```

I have this javascript between the checkbox and the form:

```
<script>
    if($("#model0x").is(':checked')){
      $("#model0_is_checked").val($("#model0x").val());
    }else{ 
      $("#model0_is_checked").val("Not Checked"); 
    }   
</script>
```

Finally, I have this hidden input to call that value inside the form when the item is checked or not:

```
 <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="final_form" action="send_mail.php">
 <input type="hidden" id="model0_is_checked" name="model0_is_checked">
   MORE FORM STUFF AND SUBMIT BUTTON 
 </form>
```

No matter what I'm getting no value in the send_mail.php ....what am I doing wrong?

Comment: how are you calling that `if()`? On page load it looks like it will return false, and unless you re-call it on form submit, or other event, it will not be re-called.

Comment: You can see the code at http://f14.co/auto-search/reno

Comment: You dont want inputs outside the <form> its bad form.

Comment: Also model0_is_checked doesnt exist yet. Your trying to set an object the browser hasnt rendered yet. Try just moving your javascript to the bottom of the page so it runs after the page has rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the function to the form submit.

```
<script>
$('#final_form').on('submit',function(){
    if($("#model0x").is(':checked')){
        $("#model0_is_checked").val($("#model0x").val()); }
    else { $("#model0_is_checked").val("Not Checked");}
});
</script>
```

jsFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/KZrLp/

Comment: Do I need to change my hidden input at all within the form?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#model0x').click(function(){
    var self=this;
    $("#model0_is_checked").val($(self).is(':checked')?self.value:'Not Checked');
    // do something
});
// or use submit ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript runs once, when the page (or more accurately, the `<script>` tag) is loaded. You have to make it run when the form is submitted instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateHidden() { // Find a better name ;)
    if($("#model0x").is(':checked'))
        $("#model0_is_checked").val($("#model0x").val());
    else
        $("#model0_is_checked").val("Not Checked");
}
$(document).ready(function() { $('#final_form').submit(updateHidden); });
</script>
```

P.S. : not tested code